# Convergence/divergence of $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^{7/2}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals

Prove that the improper integral $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^{7/2}}\ dx$$ diverge or converge.

Comment: '^7/2' is asked

Comment: You *must* enclose your formulae between dollar signs otherwise it is almost unreadable.

Comment: The result is $4\sqrt{2\pi}/15$ :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:** (1) We have potential troubles at $0$ and because the interval is infinite. Break up the integral into two parts, $0$ to (say) $1$ and $1$ to $\infty$.

(2) Deal with the "$\infty$" part. Should not be hard, the function decreases fast.

(3) For the behaviour near $0$, use the Taylor series $\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$. For $x$ near $0$, the top is $\lt \dfrac{x^3}{3}$.

(4) So for positive $x$ near $0$, our function is positive but less than a constant times $\dfrac{1}{x^{1/2}}$.