# Determine that improper integral converge or diverge

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convergence/divergence of $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^{7/2}}\ dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257281/convergence-divergence-of-int-0-infty-fracx-sin-xx7-2-dx)

Determine the improper integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^{7/2}}dx$ converge or diverge. Prove that please.

Comment: "infinity" should be "\infty" and do you mean $x^{7/2}$ or $\frac{x^7}{2}$?  (if its the first, enclose $7/2$ in curly braces: x^{7/2}

Comment: You need to analyze the badness near $0$. My approach would be the Taylor series for sine. Informally, near $0$ the top behaves like $x^3/6$.

Comment: Why did you have to ask the same question twice?

Comment: @icurays1 x^(7/2)

Answer (score 1):

Write for $0< \varepsilon<1$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}{\dfrac{x-\sin{x}}{x^{\frac{7}{2}}}\, dx}=\int\limits_{0}^{\varepsilon}{\dfrac{x-\sin{x}}{x^{\frac{7}{2}}}\, dx}+\int\limits_{\varepsilon}^{1}{\dfrac{x-\sin{x}}{x^{\frac{7}{2}}}\, dx}+\int\limits_{1}^{+\infty}{\dfrac{x-\sin{x}}{x^{\frac{7}{2}}}\, dx}.$$
Since for small $x, \;\; 0<x<\varepsilon$  $$x-\sin{x}=\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+O(x^5), $$ then
$$\dfrac{x-\sin{x}}{x^{\frac{7}{2}}}\sim {\dfrac{1}{3!}}x^{3-\frac{7}{2}}={\dfrac{1}{3!}}x^{-\frac{1}{2}},$$
therefore the first integral in RHS converges.

The second integral is proper integral, therefore it is finite.

The third integral converges, since $\left|\dfrac{x-\sin{x}}{x^{\frac{7}{2}}}\right| \leqslant \dfrac{x+1}{x^{\frac{7}{2}}} \leqslant \dfrac{2x}{x^{\frac{7}{2}}}=2x^{-\frac{5}{2}}.$

Comment: I think you mean to write $x - \sin x = x^3/3! + O(x^5)$, since it does not make sense to say that something is $o(\cdots)$ on a fixed interval.

Comment: @Antonio Vargas Thanks! Edited.